# Why does an XOR instruction cause the C flag to set to 1?

Tags: microcontroller, msp430

- I'm currently studying for an upcoming quiz in my microprocessors class and ran into a question where an XOR instruction was introduced.
- I understood why the `N flag` was set to 1, but i'm at a loss as to why the `C flag`was set to 1.
- I looked everywhere online as to why or how this might have occurred, but everything related to a C flag only talked about the arithmetic portion as to why a C flag changes.
- I'm using a `MSP430` if that helps.

[image: Picture of the XOR question]

Comment: BTW, not every CPU affects the Carry as a result of XOR.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is related to a homework/study preparation, I want to give you a hint.
The XOR operation can be used to add two binary numbers ;-)